# Using DataTrigger with more than one values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, multidatatrigger

I am using XAML code part of which is

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Course Text"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Media Lecture"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger    Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="3">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Assessment"/>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="4">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Question"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="5">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="General"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Now I want to use a dataTrigger which can have values as 3, 301, 302 or 303. How can I do this.
I tried with Multidatatrigger, but it doesn't worked. The code I tried with Multidatatrigger was:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="301"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="301"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="302"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="303"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Assessment"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Wat do u wanna achieve wid data trigger?

Comment: @user1341006 How can your property `Name` can have 5 different values at the same time ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MultiDataTrigger applies when *all* of the conditions are met not *any*, that's why your MultiDataTrigger isn't working.

Either have four separate triggers, or put the condition into a separate boolean property such as

```
bool ShowAssessment
{
    return Value == 301 || Value == 302 ...
}
```

raise a property change notification for ShowAssessment when Value changes

e.g

```
int Value { 
    get{ return _value; } 
    set { 
        _value = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShowAssessment");
    }
}
```

and then trigger on ShowAssessment.

Probably a better solution is to add a HeaderText property with a switch statement that returns the correct header text based on `Value`.  Then just bind the header's text to that.  No triggers required.

Comment: I want the trigger to apply when any one of the value satisfies. I want in one trigger only without using four triggers.

Comment: There are a couple of solutions in my answer.  One trigger for your four values, or no triggers by moving the logic into the view model.

Answer (score 0):

MultidataTrigger will act when all condition are satisfied . So

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Prop1}" Value="301"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Prop2}" Value="301"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Prop3}" Value="302"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Prop4}" Value="303"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Assessment"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

You will require a single DataTrigger

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConditionEnum}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="expanderHeader" Value="Course Text"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Set the Value of the Enum with a Defined logic in your code...

## Example :

```
Validate()
{
    if(Value == 301 || Value == 302|| ....)
    {
        ConditionEnum = MyEnum.Assessment;
    }
    //Other Conditions
}
```

I am leaving the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Use it to provide change notifications.

Comment: I want it in case the value is either 3, 301, 302 or 303. How can I do this?